# How to calculate Hall coefficient in gold and silver?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, conductors

**BACKGROUND - Hall Effect**

Using the free-electron model, the *Hall coefficient* is calculated as $$R_H = \frac{1}{ne},$$ where $e$ is the elementary charge and $n$ is the carrier density. For a metal $X$, we can also write it in the following way: $$R_H (X)= \frac{m_X N_X}{\rho_X e},$$ where $m_X$ stands for the mass of a single atom, $N_X$ is the number of valent electrons in that metal, $\rho_X$ is its mass density. Since **gold** and **silver** are both monovalent, we set $N_X = 1$.

Using this model, I obtain:
$$R_H(Au)=105.8 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
$$R_H(Ag)=106.6 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
The values I found in literature (*The Hall Effect in Metals and Alloys*, Colin Hurd, 1972) for this model are
$$R_H(Au)=106.0 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
$$R_H(Ag)=106.5 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
so I guess it's not wrong.

**THE PROBLEM**

Those coefficients don't agree with observed values (*same source*):
$$R_H(Au)=71.6 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
$$R_H(Ag)=88.1 \times 10^{-12} \, \text{m}^3 \, \text{A} \,  \text{s}$$
Those are both monovalent 1B metals with FCC structure so I understand that the *two-band* model would be a better approximation to reality. 
In that model, two types of carriers are used, **electrons** and **holes**. The book gives a simple formula for the Hall coefficient in the low-field limit, but it includes **cyclotron frequency** $\omega$, **relaxation time** $\tau$ and **effective mass** $m^{*}$ for both the holes and electrons.

I spent hours searching all over the web, but I can't seem to find a simple expression for those quantities that would be applicable to $Au$ and $Ag$. Anyone?

Comment: Are you sure about $N_X = 1$?
I think the free electrons per atom of silver, for example, is specified at about 1.3..